# Is it possible to default to an empty string instead of defaulting to the current user (and still force the selection of a user)?

Tags: tfs, workitem

As per the process template default settings, one can assign any valid user to the System.AssignedTo field.

I'm changing it so:

1. If the work item creator is from the PPQA group, he/she can only assign the workitem to somebody from the GP group.
2. Everybody else can assign the workitem to anybody contributing to the project ([Project]\Contributors)

To achieve this result, I have the following field definition:

```
<FieldDefinition reportable="dimension" refname="System.AssignedTo" name="Assigned To" syncnamechanges="true" type="String">
    <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
    <VALIDUSER for="[project]\PPQA" group="[project]\GP" />
    <VALIDUSER not="[project]\PPQA" group="[project]\Contributors" />
    <HELPTEXT>The person currently working on this issue</HELPTEXT>
</FieldDefinition>
```

This gets the job almost done, but not perfect.

In the current Team Explorer implementation (VS 2010), when a member of the PPQA group creates a new issue, his/her name appears on the *Assigned To* field by default although he/she is forced to change it choosing a name from the list (GP group).

**Is it possible to default to an empty string instead of defaulting to the current user (and still force the selection of a user)?**

I have tried both constructs below without success:

```
<DEFAULT for="[Project]\PPQA" from="value" value="" />

<COPY for="[Project]\PPQA" from="value" value="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is edition the transition (and not the field) to change the default value set to the current user to the value you want.

Open the WIT definition from the Process Template Editor (TFS Power Tools must be installed), then go to the Workflow Tab, right click on the first Transition "from [blank] to Active" and choose "Open Details".
[image]

Then go to the "Fields" tab, select the "System AssignedTo" field, then right click and Edit.
[image]

Then go to the "Rules" tab and change/edit the "Default" rule to a Value or anything else you want.
[image]